# Eloquent: case insensitive doesnt work in like sentence

Tags: laravel, eloquent, case-sensitive

I want to make a search in case in-sensitive, but doesnt work.
I try with this:

```
$query->Where(DB::raw("lower($field)"), "like", "%" . strtolower($request->search) . "%")->get();
```

And with this:

```
$query->whereRaw("lower($field) like (?)", ["%{$term}%"])->get()
```

I try with "ilike" but doesnt work in my database (MariaDB).
The weird thing is that the sql query work in in-sensitive mode when i executed it directly in my sql client (HeidiSQL).
My database is MariaDB.

Thanks

Comment: What are the collation settings for your server/database and for the client Laravel project (typically found in *config/database.php* under the *mysql* key).

Comment: @Jason is             'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',